# How to extract WiFi driver files from old version of Ubuntu and use them in new version?

Tags: wireless, ralink

My WiFi adapter (RALINK RT61 MIMO) works good with old live version of Ubuntu 7.10 (Gutsy Gibbon), I have tested most of versions released after 7.10, and it simply does not work well, or even at all, looses network, disconnects, etc. Is there a way to somehow "extract" WiFi driver from old Ubuntu version and use it in current version 16.04?

Comment: I would bet the problem isn't the driver but improper wireless network settings or other compatibility issues (a lot has changed). And such an old hardware should have been decommissioned a long time ago. For $8-10 you can get a new, faster, safer and more reliable USB WiFi adapter.